# Redirect after auto scroll javascript

Tags: javascript

I found this code which I use to auto-scroll a div on my page.

It works perfectly as is, but now I would like to add logic to redirect to a url 5 seconds after the scrolling has finished.

```
ScrollRate = 50;

function scrollDiv_init() {
    DivElmnt = document.getElementById('MyDivName');
    ReachedMaxScroll = false;
    DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
    PreviousScrollTop = 0;
    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {
    if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop++;
        ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do for accomplishing that? try to understand the code you use, this will improve you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Next time I will write what I've tried. In this case I was stuck on the part else {  }. I didn't know how to stop the interval. With the answer from Zee I search more information about clearInterval(ScrollInterval); and understand what happends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correct, once the scrolling is done you want to go to some other page. Do it like this:

```
function scrollDiv() {

if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
    DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
    PreviousScrollTop++;

    ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);   
}
else{
  clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
  setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.href = "path/to/your/file";
  },5000)//In 5 seconds
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with.

```
function scrollDiv() {
    var ScrollRate = 50;


    var DivElmnt = document.getElementById('MyDivName');
    var ReachedMaxScroll = false;
    var PreviousScrollTop  = 0;

    divElmnt.scrollTop = 0;

    setTimeout(
        function () {
            if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
                DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
                PreviousScrollTop++;

                ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            }, 5);
        },
        ScrollRate
    );
}
```